# Is there a way to move all footnotes to the end of the document?

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

Is there a way to move all footnotes to the end of the document (after the `thebibliography` environment)?

Comment: And interesting counter-question here would be: why would you want to do that? I would like to suggest reading [this](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/research-writing/citing-references/footnotes-vs-endnotes-when-to-use-them) in order to get a grip of what end- and footnotes are and when to prefer one over the other.

Comment: @rbaleksandar that link is dead, do you mind summarizing the point being made in the article? edit: [found the content via internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170702184415/http://www.write.com/writing-guides/research-writing/citing-references/footnotes-vs-endnotes-when-to-use-them/)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the [`endnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endnotes) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

text\footnote{test footnote}

\newpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

To add a horizontal rule below the "Notes" heading, you can redefine the `\enoteheading` command; for example, to obtain a rule of width equal to `0.5\textwidth` you can add the following lines to the preamble (after loading `endnotes`):

```
\makeatletter
\def\enoteheading{\section*{\notesname
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-2.3\baselineskip\noindent\rule{.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par\vskip\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

Of course, feel free to change the vertical skips according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, but how can I add a line below the "Notes"?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan a line of width rqual to the whole \textwidth or just undelining the word "Notes"?

Comment: 0.5/textwidth please.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan: please see my updated answer.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `endnotes` and `pagenote` (from the other answer)?

Comment: thanks a lot @Gonzalo Medina, It worked smoothly

Comment: Only use `\let\footnote=\endnote` if you have no intention of combining the two in one document.

Answer (score 19):

The `endnotes` package hasn't been updated since 2003 (at this writing), and doesn't work well with the KOMA-Script classes. The [`enotez`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enotez) package is more reliable and easier to customize:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enotez}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

text\footnote{test footnote}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out enotez, an excellent alternative to endnotes.

Answer (score 11):

You may use the [`pagenote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pagenote) package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}

\let\footnote\pagenote

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\printnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between `pagenotes` and `endnotes` (from the other answer)?

Comment: `pagenotes` 2004-2009. `endnotes` 2002-2004, development resumed in 2018. `enotez`  2009-2022.