# One command two (similar) actions

Tags: macros, footnotes

I was searching for an option to list all footnotes at the end of my text as well as on the same page.
I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56145/is-there-a-way-to-move-all-footnotes-to-the-end-of-the-document) answer using the package `enotez` which showed that there is a way to collect all footnotes.
But the solution redefined the `footnote` command as a whole to `endnote` (`\let\footnote=\endnote`)

So is there a way to define a new command that triggeres `endnote` and `footnote` at the same time?

[Oh, if you ask yourself why somebody wants that slightly weird solution - my sister has little Latex experience and is writing a report for maths and she started by using the footnote command and I'm here to fix it.
But I guess that this is an interesting question beside that specifc problem :)]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid printing a double footnote mark. However, I can't see how this can be useful for.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}

\newcommand{\doublenote}[1]{\endnote{#1}\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{#1}}

\setlength{\textheight}{4cm}% just to get a smaller picture

\begin{document}

This text has a double note\doublenote{Footnote here}.

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Of course, in a real document, the endnotes would go to a new page.

[image]

Comment: Hey!
Yeah, as I said that function isn't that usefull for me.
I would rather use ohter ways to give reference to my sources.
It's a workaround about a problem that ouccred because I didn'Ät have the time to assist my sister as I should have done it.
Now I'm cleaning up ;)
And we all know that it's always better to do something automatically than manually, so I took this situation as a challenge to expand my own knowledge.
Thank you for helping me with this!

Answer (score 1):

From your description I it sounds to me as if what you really want is not a command that calls `\footnote` and `\endnote` at the same time but rather to use these two interchangeably. However the solution for that you have included in your question (the `\let\footnote=\endnote` solution).

If you want one command that really calls both other commands, you'd probably have to do it something like this:

```
\newcommand{\doublenote}[1]{\footnote{#1}\endnote{#1}}
```

This is untested but in principle I *think* this should do what you want (provided you don't want to use option arguments).

Comment: Would that give you double marks?

Comment: Yeah this is what I searched for.
Thank you!