# Move footnotes in an appendix

Tags: footnotes, displaystyle

I created a document to which, over time, I had to add MANY footnotes.
Now, to make things more practical I would like to have two versions of the doc: i) the current one with many footnotes at the bottom of every page and ii) a version of the document where the footnotes are present only in an appendix.

Some of these footnotes are explaining basic stuff and are useless for folks which already work on the project but I think it's valuable to keep them to clarify the jargon when needed.

Is there an easy way to change the style of my doc to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you know endfootnotes?

Comment: Does the previous question ["Is there a way to move all footnotes to the end of the document?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56145/is-there-a-way-to-move-all-footnotes-to-the-end-of-the-document) help?

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot.